# compatibility of 14.04 and thinkpad carbon x1 2014

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad

I am not sure what Generation are those X1 laptops, so here are the specs: [shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/x-series/x1-carbon/#techspecs](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/x-series/x1-carbon/#techspecs)

Anyone with 14.04 would like to share his/her experience?
I would like to buy one but couldn't find a lot of information about 14.04.
Any issues and workarounds? [Pablo](https://askubuntu.com/users/278943/pablo) mentioned 14.04 with 2nd Gen, but I am not sure what Generation are the recent X1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

feel free to install any type of ubuntu, that computer can run it no problem. Anything with over 2gb of ram is blazing fast on kubuntu IMO, lubuntu goes down to 512mb without much stuttering